# Combining Excel worksheets over multiple loops

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a number of Excel workbooks, each with multiple worksheets, that I'd like to combine.

I've set up two sets of loops (one while, one for) to read in rows for each sheet in a given workbook and then do the same for all workbooks.

I tried to do it on a subset of these, and it appears to work until I try to combine the two sets using the pd.concat function.  Error given is

> TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you
>   passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

```
import pandas as pd    

d = 2013
numberOfSheets = 5

while d < 2015:
    #print(str(d) + ' beginning')
    f ='H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/scriptTest ' + str(d) + '.xlsx'  
    for i in range(1,numberOfSheets+1):
        data = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname = 'Table '+str(i), header=None) 
        print(i)
        df.append(data)   

    print(str(d) + ' complete')
    print(df)
    d += 1

df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)

final = "H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/mergedfile.xlsx" 
df.to_excel(final)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `pd.concat()` requires an iterable, like a list: `pd.concat([df1, df2])` will concatenate `df1` and `df2` along the default axis of 0, which means `df2` is appended to the bottom of `df1`.

Two issues need fixing:

1. The `for` loop refers to `df` before assigning anything to it.
2. The variable `df` is overwritten with each iteration of the `for` loop.

One workaround is to create an empty list of DataFrames before the loops, then append DataFrames to that list, and finally concatenate all the DataFrames in that list. Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd    

d = 2013
numberOfSheets = 5
dfs = []

while d < 2015:
    #print(str(d) + ' beginning')
    f ='H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/scriptTest ' + str(d) + '.xlsx'  
    for i in range(1, numberOfSheets + 1):
        data = pd.read_excel(f, sheetname='Table ' + str(i), header=None) 
        print(i)
        dfs.append(data)

    print(str(d) + ' complete')
    print(df)
    d += 1

# ignore_index=True gives the result a default IntegerIndex 
# starting from 0
df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(df_final)

final_path = "H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/mergedfile.xlsx" 
df_final.to_excel(final_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment, I'll leave this as an answer: you can speed up this code by opening the file once then parsing the workbook to get each sheet. Should save a second or two off each iteration, since opening the Excel file takes the longest. Here's some code that might help.

**Note**: setting `sheet_name=None` will return ALL the sheets in the workbook:

```
dfs = {<sheetname1>: <DataFrame1>, <sheetname2>: <DataFrame2>, etc.}
```

Here's the code:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fpath)
dfs = xl.parse(sheetname=None, header=None)

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    <do stuff with each, if you want>
    print('Sheet {0} looks like:\n{1}'.format(i+1, df))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, both.  I accepted the answer that addressed the specific question, but was able to use the second answer and some additional googling thereafter (eg, glob) to amend the original code, and automate more fully independent of number of workbooks or worksheets.

Final version of the above now below:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
#import numpy as np
#import os, collections, csv
#from os.path import basename    

fpath = "H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/"

dfs = []
files = glob.glob(fpath+'*.xlsx') 

for f in files:
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(f) 
    xls = xl.parse(sheetname=None, header=0)
    for i, df in enumerate(xls):
        print(i)    
        dfs.append(xls[df])   

    print(f+ ' complete')

df_final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

final = "H:/MyDocuments/Z Project Work/mergedfile.xlsx" 
df_final.to_excel(final)
```